# GWT issue 2079 error message not possible to remove

Tags: gwt, jetty, mgwt

i am using gwt and mgwt for my project. 
When i am running my project on eclipse jetty server i get the following alert error message:

> cross-site hosted mode not yet implemented. See issue http:// code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2079

and this has to do wih the following linker in the appname.gwt.xml file

```
 <add-linker name="xs" />
```

but when i remove the linker from the gwt.xml module the error is still there.
I cleaned the project and refreshed it but i get still the error message.
It's not possible to test the app in the browser any more.
How to solve the problem. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the *.nocache.js file.

BTW, `xs` linker is deprecated, use the `xsiframe` one (which supports DevMode, as stated in issue 2079)

Answer (score 1):

Replace '**xs**' to '**xsiframe**' in add-linker tag then after add this tag
`<set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>`

then rebuild project